How to get the path to a tool inside of Bazel's repository_rule impl function
I need to get the path of a tool inside of a Bazel repository_rule implementation function so that I can create a configuration file with that path. In my specific case, I would like to get the path of the Node.js binary. I have put together a MRE that demonstrates the problem. In the BUILD.bazel file there are two genrules that output a file with a path. The first genrule that directly depends on @nodejs//:node_bin as a tool works. The second genrule that depends on the filegroup inside the repository gives a nonsensical path that does not exist. In fact, after cleaning, the second genrule also does not even trigger Node.js to be fetched.
Why does the second genrule neither trigger Node.js to download or result in a correct path and how can I fix this?
repository.bzl
def _test_repository_impl(ctx):
    # neither of these give us the actual path to the nodejs binary
    ctx.file(".config", "{}".format(ctx.path(Label("@nodejs//:node_bin"))))
    #ctx.file(".config", "{}".format(ctx.path(ctx.attr._nodejs)))
    ctx.file("BUILD.bazel", """
filegroup(
    name = "config",
    srcs = [".config"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""")

test_repository = repository_rule(
    _test_repository_impl,
    attrs = {
        "_nodejs": attr.label(
            default = Label("@nodejs//:node_bin"),
        )
    }
)


MODULE.bazel
bazel_dep(name = "rules_nodejs", version = "6.3.2")

node = use_extension("@rules_nodejs//nodejs:extensions.bzl", "node")
node.toolchain(node_version = "20.14.0")
use_repo(node, "nodejs", "nodejs_toolchains")

test_repository = use_repo_rule("//:repository.bzl", "test_repository")
test_repository(name = "repository_nodejs")

BUILD.bazel
# This rule results in a relative path: external/rules_nodejs~~node~nodejs_linux_amd64/bin/nodejs/bin/node
# Running this rule after `bazel clean --expunge` causes nodejs to be fetched
genrule(
    name = "genrule_nodejs",
    outs = ["genrule_nodejs.txt"],
    cmd = "echo $(execpath @nodejs//:node_bin) >> $(OUTS)",
    tools = [
        "@nodejs//:node_bin",
    ],
)

# This rule gives us an absolute path that ends with: external/rules_nodejs~~node~nodejs/node_bin (incorrect)
# Running this rule after `bazel clean --expunge` does *not* cause nodejs to be fetched
genrule(
    name = "repository_nodejs",
    outs = ["repository_nodejs.txt"],
    cmd = "cat $(execpath @repository_nodejs//:config) >> $(OUTS)",
    tools = [
        "@repository_nodejs//:config"
    ]
)


Any thoughts on how to solve this @ahumesky ?
